# How to disable Energy Saver mode when switching to battery to stop background windows hiding?

Tags: parallels-desktop, power-management

So, Mojave appears to background all of your windows when you unplug. Then you re-plug and suddenly all your windows are out of order.

The energy saver options don't seem to have anything related to the windowing. I'm trying to turn this off so my windows stop vanishing, especially since I'm usually developing and debugging and suddenly-disappearing IDE doesn't help with the simulator.

Comment: That's not expected behaviour. Plugging or unplugging the power cable should not affect the windows in any way. Are you absolutely sure that this is being caused by unplugging? Can you describe the behaviour in clear, repeatable steps, and perhaps add a screenshot or two? Does it happen with any application, e.g. TextEdit?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that. Parallels toolbox apparently was doing it, but good luck finding the settings to disable it... (I eventually did, it's terrible UI). I will edit my question to tilt towards the 3rd party tool.  The timing made me think it was Mojave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be Parallels Toolbox. To turn it off, you have to go into the settings for Parallels Toolbox, which is in the upper-right of the main window for it, then uncheck Energy Saver. There are about 2 other areas with energy saver options, but they just turn it on/leave it on.

Hitting Cancel on one of the other screens tricked me into thinking it was off, so ensure to follow instructions above.